# Is $f(x,y(x))$ a function of two variables? If so, how is that possible?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I don't know how to interpret this function:

> Let $D$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a continuous function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  and
>   \begin{align}
> y'(x)=f(x,y(x))
> \end{align}
>   is a continuous, explicit first-order differential equation defined on $D$.

From $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I interpret $f$ as a two variable function, $f(x,y)$.

But here $y$ is a function of $x$, so isn't $f(x,y(x))$ a function of *one* variable, $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A function of $n$ variables takes $n$ parameters. Therefore, $f(x)=0$ is a function of 1 variable and $g(x,y)=0$ is a function of 2 variables even though $(\forall x,y)\,\,\,f=g$ and both functions don't depend on their parameters.

Comment: Sort of but not really.  f takes two variables but g(x) = f(x, y(x)) is not the same thing as f.  It uses f to define it but it isn't f itself.    For example if $f(x,y) = x^2 + 17xy$ takes two veriables but if we define $g(x) = f(x, \sqrt {1- x^2}) = x^2 + 17x(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ that is a function with one variable.  But it isn't $f$.  It is f restricted to limited set of values that are determined by a single variable.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f$ is a function of two variables, but the *composition* $y' = f\circ y$ is a function of one variable, taking as input $x$ and returning $f(x,y(x))$.

Comment: Thanks! So we have $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $y:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and then the composition is $y':\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, i.e. $y'(x)=(f \circ y)(x)$? Right?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Yes, that's right.

Comment: To be pedantic: $f \circ (\operatorname{id} \times y)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Is id the identity matrix and $\times$ the cross product?

Comment: @JDoeDoe: It's the identity function and the Cartesian product. Definitions: $\operatorname{id}(x)=x$ and $(f \times g)(x_1,x_2)=(f(x_1),g(x_2))$.

Answer (score 2):

Why must $f$ be the two-variable function $f(x,y)$? Why can't it be the two-variable function $f(u,v)$ instead?

The point I'm trying to make here is that when we write "$f(x,y)$ is a two-variable function," the $x$ and $y$ in this expression are just placeholders expressing the fact that you need to give $f$ a *pair* of numbers in order to get a value from it. It is not correct to give these symbols any meaning beyond that in that context; in fact, technically it may be said to be incorrect to say that "$f(x,y)$ is a two-variable function" at all,
because $f(x,y)$ is a notation that denotes the value that $f$ maps the pair $(x,y)$ to, which is a different thing from the function itself.

When we write $y'(x) = f(x,y(x)),$ however, we indicate (somewhat informally) that we have in mind that there is some function named $y$ whose derivative at a value $x$ can be deduced by letting the two-parameter function $f$ map the pair of numbers $x$ and $y(x)$ to the value of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a two variables function: $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. So, for a given $(x,y)$ it returns a value $f(x,y)$.

Now, $y'$ is a one variable function: $y':\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. So, for a given $(x)$ it returns a value $y'(x)$.

When one states that $y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$; it means that as long $f$ is evaluated in a point of the curve $(x,y(x))$ it will coincide with $y'(x)$.

What is happening is that we are reducing the domain of $f$, so it will only depend on a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $f(x, y(x))$ implies that $y$ is a function of $x$, hence $y'(x)$ is only defined on the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is on the curve $y(x)$. So, even if $f$ is defined on a larger subset writing $y'(x) = f(x, y(x))$ is restricting $f$ to values on the 1-D curve defined by $y(x)$; in this sense it is a 1-D function (whose value is the slope of the curve $y(x)$ at the point $x$).

However, there is nothing stopping $f$ from being defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, those values just won't be relevant to the differential equation.